# Odd error when capturing function parameter in Swift call to animateWithDuration:Animations:

Tags: swift, closures, animatewithduration

I'm writing some simple animation code to make a button get taller and then shorter using UIView animations. The code is a little long, but fairly simple:

```
func animateButton(aButton: UIButton, step: Int)
{
  let localStep = step - 1

  let localButton = aButton
  let halfHeight = aButton.bounds.height / 2

  var transform: CGAffineTransform
  switch step
  {
  case 2:
    //Make the center of the grow animation be the bottom center of the button
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -halfHeight)

    //Animate the button to 120% of it's normal height.
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale( transform, 1.0, 1.2)
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( transform, 0, halfHeight)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
      {
        aButton.transform = transform
      },
      completion:
      {
        (finshed) in
        //------------------------------------
        //--- This line throws the error ---
        animateButton(aButton, step: 1)
        //------------------------------------
    })
  case 1:
    //In the second step, shrink the height down to .25 of normal
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -halfHeight)

    //Animate the button to 120% of it's normal height.
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale( transform, 1.0, 0.25)
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( transform, 0, halfHeight)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
      {
        aButton.transform = transform
      },
      completion:
      {
        (finshed) in
        animateButton(aButton, step: 0)
    })
  case 0:
    //in the final step, animate the button back to full height.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5)
      {
        aButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
  default:
    break
  }
}
```

The completion blocks for the animation methods are closures. I'm getting an error "Call to method `animateButton` in closure requires explicit `self.` to make capture semantics explicit.

The thing is, the parameter aButton is a parameter to the enclosing function. There is no reference to an instance variable.

It looks to me like this is compiler bug. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think it needs `self.animateButton(aButton, step: 1)`.

Comment: That's it! I should have thought of that. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept/up-vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling methods in the same class are called with an implied `self`.  In this case because of the closure you have to make it explicit:

```
self.animateButton(aButton, step: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that, or would have if I wasn't being a bonehead. :/

Comment: No big deal.  We all have blind spots at times.